# Why naive (prediction) forecasting is called random walk?

Tags: forecasting

Why naive (prediction) forecasting is called a random walk?

Naive prediction is to use the last value as a forecast.

(It's clear that the best prediction for a random walk is a naive one.)

Answer (score 4):

One of the simplest and yet most important models in time series forecasting is the random walk model. This model assumes that in each period the variable takes a random step away from its previous value, and the steps are independently and identically distributed in size (“i.i.d.”). This is equivalent to saying that the first difference of the variable is a series to which the mean model should be applied.

In other words, it predicts that all future values will equal the last observed value. This doesn’t really mean you expect them to all be the same, but just that you think they are equally likely to be higher or lower, and you are staying on the fence as far as point predictions are concerned.

Because of this, this method is usually known as naive method.

https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/Notes_on_the_random_walk_model--Robert_Nau.pdf